# How can I get Only Health related Data from Google API?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to get only results that are related to health and for that I used below api.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=23.0225,72.5714&radius=500&types=hospital&sensor=false&key="API_KEY"

Above API gives me the results related to Health but I don't want to pass location lat long Parameter.

Actually I want to search it with **"input"** Param like below.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Ahmedabad&types=hospital&radius=500&key="API_KEY"

But above give me error like below

**{
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}**

How can I get this type of results?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: according to me, you can not do like this because city can be duplicate like Surat is in India and USA too. So how can we differenciate those cities So we have cordinates of it. That's how we can identify particular place anywhere in world.

Comment: @JitendraModi, I want to search Places with types PARAM. like if I search for "mcdonalds" than I need to get all results of mcdonalds all over the world with type "food" only. if there's any other type of mcdonalds like "mcdonalds hospital or any other" than I don't want it, it only give result related to "food" type which I specify.

Comment: You can pass type in API

Comment: @JitendraModi I pass type but it give me error, like "INVALID_REQUEST". https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=mcdonalds&types=food&radius=500&key="API_KEY"

Comment: I make project in which I use radarSearch of google api In which I have different types of hospital, policestation, gym etc. I successfully get all data from google api. If you want my first controller then I can send to you.

Comment: @JitendraModi just give me API URL by which I can get all results for particular types. In every request I am getting "INVALID_REQUEST" Error.

Comment: @JitendraModi, ok give me your first controller

Comment: take it from https://www.dropbox.com/s/ygvbpa4rz0fr6v2/ViewController.m?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The places autocomplete request from your question has several issues.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Ahmedabad&types=hospital&radius=500&key=API_KEY`

1. If you remove the `location` parameter, you should remove the `radius` parameter as well. It doesn't make sense without location.
2. `hospital` is not allowed value in types filter of autocomplete. If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types), you will see that the only possible values are:

   - geocode
   - address
   - establishment
   - (regions)
   - (cities)
3. Place autocomplete might return only 5 suggestions. I think you are looking for something different.

Also, be aware that radar search mentioned in the comments is now deprecated and will stop working in June 2018.

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html

I would suggest having a look at Places API [text search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests). Your query with Places API text search might be

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Ahmedabad&type=hospital&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The text search can return up to 60 results divided into pages of 20 results. For your particular example, I got the following output

[image]

Hope this helps!